# Is it possible to rename apps downloaded from the Windows 8 Store?

Tags: windows-8

Is this level of customization exposed to the user? I know you can rename shortcuts by going to the Start Menu folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the name of the application is held in the package manifest. To quote the MS page

> **Package identity**
>
> Each package is defined by a globally unique identifier known as the
>   package identity. The package identity consists of 5 tuples:
>
> name  The name of the package. For example, "myCompany.mySuite.myApp".

and

> **Package properties**
>
> Each package is described through its package properties, such as
>   these:
>
> DisplayName  The friendly name of the app.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464929.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Name is part of the brand name or trademark is the recognition name so I really doubt that. But you can always hexedit their resources, but this might void the licence or some checksum checking, at least for me renaming the shortcut is mostly enough.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're talking about "desktop" vs Metro/Modern apps, you can rename them in the Start Menu:

1. Right-click tile / Start Menu listing
2. Open File Location
3. In the Explorer window that opens, notice the file path -- this is where your Start Menu shortcuts are (so you can rename other programs more easily while you're there)
4. Change the shortcut name

The new name should appear on the Start Menu in a couple seconds once it's reindexed your change.

See http://www.itworld.com/windows/308063/rename-tiles-windows-8

Comment: Your answer is unnecessarily ambiguous - and does not answer the question.
The questioner explicitly asks about Windows Store apps - not desktop apps. And they do NOT have conventional shortcuts in the start menu.

Comment: Since we're dredging up 6 year old answers @UjjwalSingh, I'm pretty sure I was very explicit as to which it works for (*not* Metro/Modern), so apologies for your confusion.  At the time I didn't know (and still don't) if Windows Store apps come in different flavors, meaning that I hadn't come across any that you could rename but didn't want to preclude the possibility that it just depended on how the app was packaged.

Comment: Alright your intention was clean . Thank you for making the effort to clarify. Also you are right it is a old one.
Traditional desktop apps are not delivered through Windows store.